# Using parent class `__new__` or `__init__` method to assign default attributes for every object/instance of a sub-class

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance, magic-methods

I am trying to create a parent class - `Car` that would be able to automatically assign a unique id (using `uuid.uuid4()`), a `created_at` attribute and an `updated_at` attribute (both using the `datetime` and `dateutil` modules) to any object that would be created through the sub-classes of my parent class.

For example: When an object (`honda_civic()`) of my sub-class `Honda`, which inherits from my `Car` parent class, is created, `honda_civic` would be automatically assigned a unique id, then it will also have a time created and time updated, as well as the other attributes and methods defined in the `Honda` sub-class.

Based on my research so far, I know that I would need to define these attributes inside either of the `__new__` or `__init__` methods of my parent class `Car` (I stand to be corrected). However, I'm struggling to figure out exactly which of them should have the definitions.

I know that the `__new__` method controls object creation while the `__init__` method controls object instantiation. My confusion now is that if I define the attributes under the `__init__` method, would that not mean that each time the object is created the attributes would have to be passed as arguments? (which is definitely not ideal). What I need help with now is figuring out the syntax of defining the attributes under the `__new__` method because I am a bit confused by the `def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)` prototype definition of the `__new__` method and how it can accommodate the definitions; can I pass the attributes to the `__new__` prototype? like so: `def __new__(cls, id, created_at, updated_at)`

Comment: *"if I define the attributes under the `__init__` method, would that not mean that each time the object is created the attributes would have to be passed as arguments?"* — No!? Just do `self.id = uuid4()` inside `__init__`…!? `__init__` *can* accept arguments passed when instantiating the class, but it doesn't _have_ to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are overcomplicating this. `Car.__init__` should perform initialization that is common to *any* `Car`, regardless of the specific subclass used to instantiated the object.

```
class Car:
   def __init__(self):
       self.id = uuid.uuid4()
       now = datetime.datetime.now()
       self.created_at = now
       self.modified_at = now
```

Each subclass will define an `__init__` method that first calls its inherited `__init__` method, then does any subclass-specific intialization.

```
class Honda(Car):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.something_else = ...
        ...

civic = Honda()
```

`civic.id`, `civic.created_at`, and `civic.modified_at` are defined by `Car.__init__`; `civic.something_else` is defined by `Honda.__init__`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was very helpful. Turns out I was indeed over thinking and over complicating

Answer (score 1):

In Python you will rarely need to touch `__new__` - and usually only when you really know what you are doing. Which means: when in doubt, use `__init__`. :-)

But seriously, the tasks you mention are typical, and meant to be done on `__init__`.

There are a few semantic and historic reasons for it - but actually, also, very practical reasons few people are aware of:

Among other things Python can do, there is out-of-the box support for serializing and de-serializing almost any object created by a user-defined class - out of the box, without the class author never worrying about it.

And one of the reasons that works in such a fine way is this separation of the construction of an object in the `__new__` and `__init__`  methods: `__new__` is supposed to build the object as an "empty shell", and `__init__` to "fill in any attributes needed at object initialization" (not quotes, I am wording these now). The de-serialization mechanism uses that to create a new object, and them just filling in the attributes of the originally serialized objects into the new instance, without calling `__init__`. In your example, if `__new__` would create an ID (which might be backed up in some registry or DB at creation, or be an immutable attribute), this mechanism would not work.